# Apache Spark: when does spark cleanup disk cache (persist() w/ StorageLevel.useDisk == true)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to figure out when Spark cleanup after an app that persist some data to disk.
Looking at the code, it seems that ContextCleaner.keepCleaning() is using best-effort approach to cleanup (the latest when SparkContext.stop() is called).

I couldn't figure out what happens id the cleanup fails, specifically is there a maintenance task that would handle it?

If not, what is the recommended way to ensure such cleanup would be done (we could create a demon, but how should we configure it so it will find the right files and is it required?).

We need to have a deterministic mechanism since the cluster handles data that can contain PII and we need to provide guarantees that it will be cleared to maintain compliance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which spark version you are using. As you mentioned, Spark has a cleaning thread, which is used to remove unused(weakly-reachable) objects automatically through a weak reference queue. Since this thread is set to be daemon, and it doesn't throw the exceptions inside, I think the main thread will continue running even though the cleaning thread exits.

Comment: Thanks,
I'm currently using Spark 2.3.0
To clarify my question - I'm not asking what happens to the app itself, I'm asking what happens to the data on the disk if there are errors.
We are using cloud storage as our backend, so failures in cleanup will happen.
The question is what happens then (is there an attempt by Spark to rerun)?

Comment: @AmosOrtal If only the cleanup thread fails, I don't think it will rerun. As you can see in your own cluster, there are always a lot of history useless files retained in the tmp dir of spark. I believe that may be the rdd files if the cleanup thread fails.